# How to access Drupal variables in a PHP included file?

Tags: 7

I have a snippet of HTML that I've saved in my theme as mysnippet.inc. I'm using this code in template files (eg. node.tpl.php) to include it:

```
<?php include($directory."/includes/mysnippet.inc"); ?>
```

This is working fine, but the snippet also needs to access Drupal variable $node_url. So I tried to global it into my snippet:

```
<?php global $node_url ; ?>
<?php print $node_url; ?>
```

This doesn't work.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Should I be using template.php to create a variable containing my code snippet instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to:

**1.** Create a custom theme function using [hook_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7).

**2.** Implement a preprocessor in your template.php (you can also do it in a custom module). [Here's a D.O. document describing how to do it.](http://drupal.org/node/223430) Assuming you want to preprocess the node.tpl.php template, a preprocessor that would be run regardless of what theme you are using would be called `phptemplate_preprocess_node`.

**3.** Inside your preprocessor, call the custom [`theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/7) function you created in step #1. Add the results of your theme function to the $variables array that are passed to your preprocessor. For example:

```
<?php
// In your template.php...
function phptemplate_preprocess_node($variables) {
  $variables['foo_bar'] = theme('my_theming_func', $params);
}
```

**4.** Now on node.tpl.php all you have to do is:

```
<?php
if(isset($foo_bar)):
  print $foo_bar;
endif;
```

I know that this sounds more difficult than what you where trying to do, however using PHP globals in Drupal and `include_once` in templates is highly discouraged.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed, clear answer. Am I right that step 1 (create custom theme function) would be done with a custom module?

Comment: @pushka Yes. You implement hook_theme() in your custom module. You substitute the word hook for the name of your module. So if your module is called pushka, your hook_theme() implementation would be written like `function pushka_theme() { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `$variables` array in your included file like this:

```
 // assuming you are viewing a node
 $node = $variables['node'];
 // the node is an object, so to display the url do
 echo drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.$node->nid);
```

To see what kind of data the `$variables` array contains do something like:

```
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($variables);
 echo '</pre>';
```